# Visual Basic - Counting the occurrence of numbers from a random array

Tags: vb.net

I need to use arrays and strings. The program should just search for 1 number which the user will enter (0-9). Here is my code below. It uses an array to get a random number, and it's testing the occurrences for each number. However it's not working, but I don't need it to test for every number anyway.

The program must only test for the 1 number that the user requests. So if the random number that's generated is say.. '7417', and user user has chosen '7', then the program will report back there have been two sevens. I'm going to use a textbox 'txtEnter' to get the users number to search for. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Randomize()
  Dim ArrayNum(1) As Integer
  ArrayNum(0) = Int(Rnd() * 100000)

  lblDisplayNumber.Text = ArrayNum(0)

  Dim num As Integer
  txtEnter.Text = num
  Dim counts = From c In num.ToString()
               Group By c Into Group
               Select DigitGroup = New With {.Count = Group.Count(),
                                             .Digit = c, .Group = Group}
               Order By DigitGroup.Count Descending
               Select String.Format("There are {0} number {1}'s found.",
                                     DigitGroup.Count, DigitGroup.Digit)
  Dim message = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, counts)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Linq, it's short and readable:

```
Dim counts = From c In num.ToString()
             Group By c Into Group
             Select DigitGroup = New With {.Count = Group.Count(), .Digit = c, .Group = Group }
             Order By DigitGroup.Count Descending
             Select String.Format("There are {0} number {1}'s found.",
                                   DigitGroup.Count, DigitGroup.Digit)
Dim message = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, counts)
```

**Update**: Here is a complete sample which shows the result of the entered number and a summary:

```
Dim rnd As New Random()
Dim randomInt = rnd.Next(0, 100000)
lblDisplayNumber.Text = randomInt.ToString()

Dim num As Integer
If Int32.TryParse(txtEnter.Text, num) AndAlso num >= 0 AndAlso num < 10 Then
    Dim counts = From c In randomInt.ToString()
             Group By c Into Group
             Select DigitGroup = New With {.Count = Group.Count(), .Digit = c, .Group = Group}
             Order By DigitGroup.Count Descending, DigitGroup.Digit
    Dim numCount = counts.FirstOrDefault(Function(grp) grp.Digit.ToString() = num.ToString())
    If numCount IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim numMessage = String.Format("There are {0} number {1}'s found.", numCount.Count, num)
        MessageBox.Show(numMessage)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Number does not contain " & num)
    End If
    Dim summaryCount = From grp In counts
                       Select String.Format("There are {0} number {1}'s found.", grp.Count, grp.Digit)
    Dim summaryMessage = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, summaryCount)
    MessageBox.Show("Summary:" & Environment.NewLine & summaryMessage)
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number between 0 and 9.")
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to replace this code that you posted directly below the case statements (so I got rid of the rest of the code below that). I'm getting this error "Local variable 'counts' is already declared in the current block." I tried getting rid of the other counts declaration but it just created more errors. Can you help? Is this what I was supposed to do?

Comment: @BillStack: "Below the case statement"? You can replace the entire code with it ;-)  You got the compiler error because you have already declared a variable with the same name: `Dim counts(9) As Integer`. If you want to use my code you have to use at least .NET 3.5 and `Imports System.Linq`. My variable `num` is one of your integers which were entered by the user.

Comment: UGH! I edited my code with your code, what am I not doing right? I wish I understood programming, sorry to take up your time!

Comment: @BillStack: The linq query shows the result for all digits in the number. If you want to use it to check the count for the number the user has entered you need to use `Enumerbale.Where`. Wait, i'll edit my answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several issues, but to give you an answer directly to what is missing:

you should convert your random number to a string first

```
 Number= Int(Rnd() * 100000) 
 NumberString = Number.ToString()
```

convert that string to an array of characters

```
 DigitArray = NumberString.ToCharArray()
```

then loop over all characters of the array and convert each character `c` back to an integer

```
 For Each c As Char In DigitArray
     num = c - "0"C`
```

Then use that `num` as index for your `counts` array

```
     count(num)+=1
```

instead of that horrible `switch` statement. I let you figure out the correct `Dim`statements for those variables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but wow my head is spinning. I'm a novice programmer and can't really follow all of that. I know it's sad but I've been stuck with this code not working and can't figure out the issues

Comment: @BillStack: see my edit, I tried to make my simple explanation even more simple, if you don't understand it know, I can't help you.

Comment: I tried playing with that but.. didn't come up with anything. Thanks anyway, though. I'm a lost cause

Answer (score 1):

The solutions presented earlier seem a bit complicated if you just need to find how many times the entered number is in the random digits.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' create the data
    Dim nDigits As Integer = 5
    Dim digits(nDigits - 1) As String
    For i = 0 To nDigits - 1
        digits(i) = CInt(Rnd() * 10).ToString
    Next

    ' show the data
    TextBox1.Text = String.Join("", digits)

    Dim inp = InputBox("Enter a number from 0 to 9")

    ' count the occurrences of the entered number
    Dim nFound = digits.Count(Function(d) d = inp)

    MsgBox(String.Format("There are {0} occurrences of {1}.", nFound, inp))

End Sub
```